# Is spark:Scale the best way to let users zoom in/out on some part of an app?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, zooming

I've been fooling with various ways to zoom objects inside my Flex app and I would love to hear if there's a universally considered best practice. Think slider that lets you zoom in/out on a set of graphical objects + potentially a marquee zoom a la Illustrator.

thank you all, as usual!

f